# UICollectionView - UICollectionViewDelegate - how do I implement the equivalent to canEditRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

Seems it'd be something to do with this method, though I'm stumped how to distinguish what Selector is being called:

```
-(BOOL)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView canPerformAction:(SEL)action forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withSender:(id)sender
{
     if ( action.type? name? == "willMoveToIndexPath"  && sender == cellToNotMove?? )  return NO;

     return YES;
}
```

Seems something like this might work, any suggestions for a clean implementation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks pretty good to me, except use `action == @selector(willMoveToIndexPath)`.